# Can't make alias of a nework location in WAMP Apache

Tags: apache, wamp, alias, file-sharing

This is vgs5.conf saved to C:/wamp/

```
Alias /vgs5/ "//Serv-lt/vgs5" 

<Directory "//Serv-lt/vgs5">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I go to [http://127.0.0.1/vgs5] using firefox it shows me the directory contents.
When I go to [http://127.0.0.1/vgs5/xxx.pdf] using firefox it shows 404 Not Found. Although the file xxx.pdf does exist and is viewable at \\Serv-lt\vgs5\xxx.pdf in adobe.

WampServer Version 2.2
Apache 2.2.22

Comment: do Alias /vgs5 (without the last "/") , verify alo path of pdf document if it's absolute or relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked

```
Alias /vgs5 "//Serv-lt/vgs5" 
<Directory "//Serv-lt/vgs5">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```